# Append Data in Nested object

Tags: elasticsearch

Edit :

I am using elasticsearch 5.5

JSON Structure is like

```
{
    "id":"123",
    "address":[{
                "id":"address_id_1",
                "state":"",
                "country":""
              }]
}
```

So My Requirement is  Like I have a index Account and in that index I have a nested object as Address with every object in address contains a field "id" as  unique. So basically What I need to do is  when i hit the update api in elastic search then the behaviour should be like this.

**1. if the address object already exist then it just needs to be updated.**

**2. if the address object  does not exist but address nested field exist then the new address should be appended to the address nested field.**

**3. if address nested field not exist then it should be created as per the input.**

Comment: What is your question?  Also, you left out code, json structure, and ES version, all of which should be present.

Comment: Just Edit my question. Thanks for Feedback